# Issue with using mysqli statement as a function return

Tags: php, function, mysqli, return

This is my model function:

```
  public function getAllArticles(){
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("select * from articles where 1 = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $title, $excerpt, $content, $created_at, $updated_at);
    return $stmt;
}
```

I'm trying to return the mysqli statement as my function return to assign it as a function call value to a variable inside this function:

```
 public function index(){
    $model = new IndexModel();
    $out = $model->getAllArticles();
    Template::render('index', THEME_FOLDER, ['results' => $out]);
}
```

And this is the render function which tries to return the correct theme:

```
 public static function render($theme, $base_folder = THEME_FOLDER, $var = null){
    $theme = str_replace('.php', '', $theme);
    if(!self::theme_exists($theme, $base_folder))
        die("Template {$theme}.php could not be found in the {$base_folder} Directory.");
    require_once ($base_folder . $theme . '.php');
}
```

And this is index.php, where I try to loop over `$var['results']->fetch()` but O got this every time:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiche\theme\index.php on line 15
```

And this is index.php:

```
    <?php
    $statement = $var['results'];
    while ($statement->fetch()){
        echo $name;
    }
?>
```

PS: When I use $stmt->fetch() in IndexModel.php (`getAllArticles()`) I could get the proper results. but when I return $stmt as function call value, I could not use the returned mysqli statement with fetch() function:

```
    public function getAllArticles(){
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("select * from articles where 1 = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $title, $excerpt, $content, $created_at, $updated_at);
    //return $stmt;
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error says your variable `$name` is not defined... Where are you getting the variables from to pass into `bind_result()`?

Comment: post edited. please check that.

Comment: Again, where is your variable $name being set? I don't see you setting it anywhere so it's no suprise your error says its undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[bind_result](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)** sets the variables in the local scope of the function. You are not returning the variables correctly. You are only returning **$stmt**. You need to fetch the results in the function and then to return the result. An example:

```
$results = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $results[] = [
       'name': $name,
    ];
}
return $results;
```

So you are currently trying to access a variable outside of the function in which the variable is defined. (**bind_results** is *setting* the variables).

Here is a link to the PHP docs about scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.